# Create a Hibernate Criteria sentence from sql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

How can I create a Hibernate Criteria from this SQL query???

```
select di.*
from device_information di,
category_product cp
where di.ID_CATEGORY_PRODUCT=cp.ID
and cp.ID_INTERNAL_GROUP= 345
```

Actually I have this code line:

> Criteria criteria =
>           getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DeviceInformation.class);
>       criteria.createCriteria("categoryProduct");
>       criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("internalGroup",internalGroupSelected));
>       criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
>
> ```
> List list=criteria.list();
> ```

But I have this error: **could not resolve property: internalGroup of: com.as5fx.business.model.DeviceInformation**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the `internalGroup` property in your `category_product`, so you cannot find that when you are querying on `DeviceInformation`.
Try like below if you have a relationship between `DeviceInformation` and `categoryProduct`:

```
List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DeviceInformation.class,"deviceInformation")
    .createAlias("deviceInformation.categoryProduct","product")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("product.internalGroup",internalGroupSelected))
    .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```